# Shader Resource Binding

Tags: shaders, directx11, hlsl

Im trying to set a constant buffer in my shader with a value. But getting nothing, no results.

Code in shader

```
cbuffer MatrixBuffer : register(b0)
{
    float4 test;
};

----------------------------------------------------------------
In main part



#pragma pack(push,1)
struct CB_GBUFFER_UNPACK
{
    D3DXVECTOR4 test;

};
#pragma pack(pop)    

            D3D11_BUFFER_DESC cbDesc;
        ZeroMemory( &cbDesc, sizeof(cbDesc) );
        cbDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
        cbDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER;
        cbDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
        cbDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof( CB_GBUFFER_UNPACK );
        device->CreateBuffer( &cbDesc, NULL, &m_pGBufferUnpackCB  );


            D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE MappedResource;
            ic->Map( m_pGBufferUnpackCB, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &MappedResource  );
            CB_GBUFFER_UNPACK* pGBufferUnpackCB = ( CB_GBUFFER_UNPACK* )MappedResource.pData;

            pGBufferUnpackCB->test.x = 10.0f;
            pGBufferUnpackCB->test.y = 10.0f;
            pGBufferUnpackCB->test.z = 10.0f;
            pGBufferUnpackCB->test.w = 0.0f;

            ic->Unmap( m_pGBufferUnpackCB, 0 );
            ic->PSSetConstantBuffers( 0, 1, &m_pGBufferUnpackCB );
```

What seems to be my problem?

Comment: Enable the debug layer by setting the D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG when creating your graphics device. Then look out for error/warning messages in the output window in your IDE.
And try to use a graphics debugger as well to inspect data in the vram.

Comment: Will it work on a .FX shader file. Or must it be a .HLSL file?

Comment: The debug layer will work for fx files, a graphics debugger might not because it is a deprecated API for a long time now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to set the Vertex Shader. But you write:

`ic->PSSetConstantBuffers( 0, 1, &m_pGBufferUnpackCB );`

It sets the PixelShader ("PSSetConstantBuffers").
Change "PS" to "VS" (VertexShader)

`ic->VSSetConstantBuffers( 0, 1, &m_pGBufferUnpackCB );`